# Error installin ruby 3.0.2 with rvm in mac os

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

`Error running 'env CFLAGS=-O3 -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib ./configure --prefix=/Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',`
this error occurs when i try to `rvm install 3.0.2`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be openssl error

Firstly install openssl@1.1 if it's not there by:

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```

Then check for the openssl installed path with:

```
brew --prefix openssl@1.1
```

Then try to install ruby with rvm like:

```
rvm install 3.0.2 --with-openssl-dir=<open-ssl-installed-path>`
```

Sometimes it says ruby is already installed then please try `reinstall` in the above command